# Login Flow Navigation using FutureBuilder: Flutter?

Tags: flutter, authentication, flutter-navigation, flutter-futurebuilder

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<AppThemeNotifier>(
      builder: (BuildContext context, AppThemeNotifier value, Widget child) {
        return Provider(
          create: "XXXXXXX",
          dispose: "XXXXXXX",
          child: MaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              theme: AppTheme.getThemeFromThemeMode(value.themeMode()),
              home: Base()),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class Base extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BaseState createState() => _BaseState();
}

class _BaseState extends State<Base> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<SessionAuth>(
      future: Provider.of<AppThemeNotifier>(context, listen: false).validate,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          SessionAuth session = new SessionAuth();
          if (session.userId != null && session.isLoggedIn) {
            return FullApp();
          } else if (isFirst) {
            return OnBoardingScreen();
          }
          return LoginScreen();
        } else {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I was trying to navigate different screens based on session validation is done through the provider package. (Login Flow Management)

Simply, I want to replace the Screens based on session details

**Break Down**

- If `userId` is not equal to null and `isLoggedin` is `true` -> FullApp
- else If user `isFirst` is `true` -> OnBoardingScreen
- else Login Screen

**Error**

- flutter: The method '>=' was called on null.
- flutter: Receiver: null
- flutter: Tried calling: >=(0.0)

**SessionAuth**

```
class SessionAuth {
  SessionAuth({this.isLoggedIn, this.userId, this.isFirst});
  int userId;
  bool isLoggedIn;
  bool isFirst;
}
```

**validate**

```
Future<SessionAuth> get validate async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  SessionAuth auth = new SessionAuth();
  auth.userId = prefs.getInt('userId') ?? null;
  auth.isLoggedIn = prefs.getBool('isLoggedIn') ?? false;
  auth.isFirst = prefs.getBool("isFirst") ?? null;

  return auth;
}
```

Comment: `SessionAuth` content ? Can you post it ?

Comment: snapshot should have the response for your future yo do not need to initialize it again inside the builder

Comment: what you are getting in `auth`